# Dockerfile for awscli

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, containers, aws-cli

I am trying to create a docker file that will install awscli and run the command to list s3. Once the command is executed the container itself exits.I builrd the image with this command `docker build --tag aws-cli:1.0 .` I am running the this docker file after building it with this command `docker run -it --rm -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION='[your region]' -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='[your access ID]' -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='[your access key]' aws-cli`
Error: `Unable to find image 'aws-cli:latest' locally docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for aws-cli, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.`

```
FROM python:2.7-alpine3.10
ENV AWS_DEFAULT_REGION='[your region]'
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='[your access key id]'
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='[your secret]'
RUN pip install awscli
CMD s3 ls
ENTRYPOINT [ "awscli" ]
```

Comment: you missed image name. Please provide image name while running docker run. like this ```docker run -it --rm -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION='[your region]' -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='[your access ID]' -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='[your access key]' <image_name>```

Comment: I build the image with this command `docker build --tag aws-cli:1.0 .` and then ran the image with this command `docker run -it --rm -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION='[your region]' -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='[your access ID]' -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='[your access key]' aws-cli` It gives an error `Unable to find image 'aws-cli:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for aws-cli, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the image name in the docker run command. It should be like this

```
docker run -it --rm -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION='[your region]' -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='[your access ID]' -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='[your access key]' <docker image>
```

Comment: That is because `awscli` command is not present in the $PATH

Answer (score 1):

You missed image name. Please provide image name while running docker run. like this

`docker run -it --rm -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION='[your region]' -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='[your access ID]' -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='[your access key]' aws-cli:1.0`